# Make items none BOLD

Tags: itemize

I am adding a list of math notations to my doc, but some symbols are bold - which should not be, as e.g. the symbol denoting matrix notation - what can I do?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}

\begin{description} 

    \item[cov(X)] Covariance or random variable X
    \item[var(X)] Variance of random variable X
    \item[corr(X,Y)] Correlation between random variables X and Y
    \item[X] Matrix X



\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Technically this should not only be non-bold but also using math mode.

Comment: For non-bold and math mode, one could use `\item[$X$] Matrix X`.

Comment: Perhaps you want to take a look at the [`nomencl`](https://ctan.org/pkg/nomencl) package.

Comment: [$X$] makes it italic...will check nomencl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain what you want with the `font=` key from `enumitem.

However I propose a solution that I think better: redefine the `\descriptionlabel` command within an `eqdescription`  environments, which clones the description environment, except it uses a normal font, and all labels are contained in a box  which has the width of the widest label, thanks to the `eqparbox` package (requires two compilations):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{mathtools, amsfonts}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{eqparbox, etoolbox}

\newlist{eqdescription}{description}{1}
 \AtBeginEnvironment{eqdescription}{%
 \renewcommand*\descriptionlabel[1]{\hspace\labelsep\eqmakebox[Des][l]{\normalfont #1}}%
 \setlist[eqdescription]{leftmargin = \dimexpr\eqboxwidth{Des}+\labelsep}}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[font=\normalfont]
    \item[cov(X)] Covariance or random variable X.
    \item[var(X)] Variance of random variable X.
    \item[corr(X,Y)] Correlation between random variables X and Y.
    \item[X] Matrix X
\end{description}
\vskip1cm
\begin{eqdescription}%
    \item[cov(X)] Covariance or random variable X.
    \item[var(X)] Variance of random variable X.
    \item[corr(X,Y)] Correlation between random variables X and Y. Correlation between random variables X and Y.
    \item[X] Matrix X
\end{eqdescription}

\end{document}
```

[image]